# Need assistance regarding @property concepts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was working on corelocation and worte this code

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    //[locationManager setDistanceFilter:0.0f];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations { 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

but my delegate method was not working, after 15 - 20 I realised that I didn't create the property of CLLocationManager `@property (strong, nonatomic)  CLLocationManager *locationManager;`

After doing this all worked fine, no issues. I have experienced this several times, some time things work without creating `@property` and sometimes thing absolutely don't work without creating `@property`.

I know `@property @synthesize` create getter setter that automatically include memory management that prevent object to destroy immediately, but how sometime code works without creating `@property`?

**Edit:**

I create a new class name `MyClass`

Myclass.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
-(void)giveMeOk;
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void)giveMeOk {
    NSLog(@"Its Ok.");
}

@end
```

In my view controller where I wrote corelocation code, in its `viewdidload` I did this:

```
.
.
.
MyClass *myClassObj = [[MyClass alloc]init];

    [myClassObj giveMeOk];
.
.
.
```

and in console `Its Ok.` print successfully, so it worked without `@property`.

Comment: i dont unserstand. you say you solved your problem by creating a property. your code doesnt show a property, but a local variable. please specify your question, its kinda hard to answer like this. thanks. Also, are you using ARC?

Comment: Properties are not required to write objective-C code.  In fact, they are nothing more than autogenerated methods and variables.

Comment: Please, define what you mean by "don't work". What kind of behaviour did you expect? What result did you get instead?

Comment: please view my question again I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you might be having is when you don't "create a property" you are using a local variable. The difference being that once the scope of that variable has ended (typically the end of the method it is created in), it will be released, so delegate methods like location manager ones wont be called (because there is no longer an object to call them, even though your delegate still exists)

By creating a property you are increasing the objects retain count, making sure the life of that object lasts beyond the method it is created in

Update:

You update makes me think I'm right. The problem is you are not understanding the lifecycle of an object: a local variable only exists for the scope it is created in (so for your example: after viewDidLoad is run, myClassObj doesn't exist any more). For something which needs to continue to do work after that method (i.e. a location manager which essentially just polls the hardwares GPS), you need a property because it needs to be retained long enough to do its work. For something which immediately does its job (like your example class, which just performs a log and returns, i.e. nothing asynchronous) a local variable is fine

Comment: that update makes me think i'm right. the problem is you are not understanding the lifecycle of an object. a local variable only exists for the scope it is created in, for something which needs to continue to do work after that method (i.e. a location manager), you need a property. for something which immediately does its job (like your example class) a local variable is fine

Answer (score 0):

As you say, a property generates a getter and setter method and manages your memory. What you didn't say is that it creates an instance variable. This is what makes your code work as it retains the instance of your location manager (otherwise it's released - assuming you're using ARC).

When you say 'sometimes it works', you need to give examples. But, it can only mean that some other class is retaining the instance you created...

Comment: @wattson12 answer above perfectly describes your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up properties with instance variables. Properties are required only when you want to access a property from external. The caller does not even care whether the property corresponds to an instance variable or not or which one, altough it is quite common that there is an insance variable and in lots of cases it is called _abc or abc when the property (and tehrefore teh getter) is called abc. If you don't synthesize it then an instance variable _abc is reated of the same type.

It is the instance variable that holds the actual data.

When you do not need to access it from external then you can declare an instance variable without a property. 
As properties are quite convenient, you may opt for declaring a property but within the *.m file.

What you do is kinda dangerous. When you declare a property `locationManager` and then locally within a method or an if-block or for-loop or whatever declare `CLLocationManager *locationManager` then you deal with a local variable of the same name. That is perfectly legal but likely to cause errors. Outside of the scope of the local `locationManager` there is still the property available. But that grants access to another object of the same type and name!